# Simple WebApp - Upload file to S3 via HTML / AWS Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

Im just starting down my dev journey and need some advice on how to approach a simple app I'm working on. I do not have a good understanding of 
modern web development.

**What I am looking to achieve is to upload a video or image via a browser form / html form to Amazon S3.**

Ideally, I want to leverage the AWS node.js SDK but keep my front end as basic as possible (i.e bootstrap page + html changes) I acknowledge that I could do a straight http operation but would still like to leverage the SDK for now.

I have my html,form and css created (using bootstrap), but do not understand how to connect the form to a node.js script that does the authorization/PUT?

Can I even go from the form, and pass the file to the script to be uploaded?

Thanks for any advice!!! :D

Comment: You cannot do it straight from the browser. You need to write some backend code that's gonna upload file to AWS.

Comment: @jimmyweb It is possible to upload from browser using AWS JavaScript SDK for S3. You will need a backend to authorize if its a private bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the AWS documentation. They even have an example for your use case: [Uploading Photos to Amazon S3 from a Browser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use, [AWS CloudFront Signed URLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) to perform the upload. The flow involved are as follows.

1. From the browser, you will request for a url, with an expiration time, to allow upload a file to a bucket. You can write Sign url creation using NodeJS Backend and AWS SDK as given in [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/creating-amazon-cloudfront-signed-urls-in-node-js/) example, after authenticating the user.
2. Using the Signed URL and [AWS JavaScript SDK for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html), browser can directly upload the file to S3.

For more information about Signed URLs, check [How Signed URLs Work](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html#private-content-how-signed-urls-work).